# Language selection for print button

Tags: buttons, ux-field, language

I'm pretty stuck with this one:
I have an explicit 'print' button but we also need to allow users to select the language in which they want the form to be printed. Adding a dropdown next to it before the button feels quite weird. Appreciate your help.

Comment: A dropdown next to the button sounds perfectly reasonable and intuitive to me. If there is a sensible default, you could have a split button with that as the primary action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the app I'm working on, we're introducing a "combo button" that defaults to one command, but, when the arrow is clicked, offers other commands.

The app uses a small "Actions" button that pops up a little panel with commands in it. Functionally similar to the combo button, just visually different.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdjbnL.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: Just wanted to make sure. I sometimes feel things look weird when in fact it's just me being weird. Thanks guys.